# Report vertical grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following tables:

```
Person:
Person_Id,
Name

Dog:
Dog_Id,
Person_Id,
Name
```

I want to show all the dogs below Person name in SSRS report. But When I add parent group, it adds to the left, so I can display dogs only to the right. (I use table control)

So: I want this:

```
Alex
DogName1
DogName2

Kristy
DogName3
DogName4
```

But the only way I can get in SSRS is:

```
Alex   DogName1
       DogName2
Krisy  DogName3
       DogName4
```

What kind of grouping should I use in order to make this work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Include group header, detail and group footer level rows in your report
- Insert Person name into the group header
- Insert Dog Name into the detail level cell, directly under Person name
- Insert a blank cell into the group footer (to skip a line between People)

EDIT: Instead of using two datasets, use one dataset with a query like the following:

```
select p.name person_name,
       d.name dog_name
from person p
inner join dog d on p.person_id = d.person_id
```

(Change `inner join` to `left outer join` if you want to include people who don't own dogs).

Comment: How do I do first item on the list in my report? I cannot find group header and other stuff anywhere.

Comment: And delete the column (but not the group) from your initial grouping.

Comment: Also, How can I add two datasets to one table control?

Comment: Thanks for the query suggestion. This is how I did it, but can you send a screenshot of where can I find group header, detail and footer level rows. thanks!

Comment: @user194076, normally group header, detail and group footer rows are fairly clearly indicated in the Report designer. Can you include a screenshot of your design view?

Comment: please see updated picture in the question. I add person_Id in header and add dog_name in detail. Now it show only one person_Id and all dog names.